# Error in my programming code

Tags: c++

I do my first course in Programming c++, and I don't know why my program doesn't work correctly. Is anyone is able to help me? Is there a way to know how many loop round I did before my loop stops (that is, when p = 0 in this case)?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    float p, i, m;

    cout << " Indiquer le montant du prêt($), le taux d'intérêt par an(%), et le payement mensuel($) :";
    cin >> p >> i >> m;

    do
    {
        float * s; 
        s = &(p*i/12*100); 
        cout << p-(m-s); 

    } while (p != 0)



    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is bad `&(p*i/12*100)` don't take the address of a temporary

Comment: `p-(m-s)` makes no sense, p/m are floats, s is a *pointer* to a float...

Comment: Why do you even have a _pointer_ to a float? You simply have a calculation.

Comment: Why a pointer make no sense here

Comment: @J.G The better question is why do *you* think it does? Find out why and you're one step closer to understanding pointers (you don't if you think it makes sense here.)

Comment: @Borgleader Thank you, your answer is a great help. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using do...while loop, while should end up with ';'.

```
do
 {
    float  s; 
    s = (p*i/12*100); 
    cout << p-(m-s); 

} while (p != 0);
```

And ignore the pointers, Because there is no need of it...

Answer (score 0):

```
    float * s; 
    s = &(p*i/12*100);
```

This is pointer, you have no allocation in your code.

And you lack of semicolon. Basics, basics ...

```
do
{
    float s; // remove *
    s = p*i/12*100; // remove &
    cout << p-(m-s); 

} while (p != 0); //semicolon
```

And this:

```
&(p*i/12*100);
```

Address of temporary value is always wrong.